# Valid uses of sentence that doesn't include relative pronouns before its main verb, but a relative pronoun should be used

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

- Going to the World Cup was a dream **come** true.

Do you think that this sentence is correct? I don't think so. It seems to me the right form of **come** should be **comes**, and we should place a pronoun like **which, that** before **comes**. Please say what you think. When are the usages of such kinds of sentence valid?

Comment: **[a dream come true](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+dream+come+true)** is an idiom. It serves as an indivisible noun phrase. Idioms are usually not analyzed as sum of their parts, although "come true" could be said to function as a postpositive adjective. Or the whole could be seen as an ellipsis of "a dream [that has] come true".

Comment: I like the last, the reduced clause explanation, best. A wish come true, a dream come true, a prophesy come true, a life gone astray, a crowd run amok.

Comment: Similar constructions occur with *gone* (e.g. "good food gone bad") and *turned* (e.g. "a big-city cop-turned-vigilante").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments have it right. It means *a dream that has come true* and "that has" can be omitted. This works generally for several specific verbs (*run*, *gone*, *turned*). For some constructions it doesn't work:

> A man that has become king

**Cannot** be rephrased to:

> *A man become king

*Run* only works in certain usages, such as *run amok* or *run rampant*. Even these usages might be a little questionable.

> The athlete that has run a mile

**Cannot** be rephrased to:

> *The athlete run a mile

Additionally, *a dream come true* is itself a very common idiomatic expression which is rarely phrased any other way (unless the author is intentionally avoiding the idiom).

---

Also note that this is similar- but not the same as -the omission of *that has been*. For example,

> A man that has been crowned king

Can be rephrased as

> A man crowned king

This construction, unlike the one in the original question, works for far more verbs and is far less idiomatic.